# Trying to define a select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to define a select tag in my view. 
My view looks like this:

```
  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :analyst %><br />
<%= select_tag :sub_category_analyst, options_for_select(analyst_names, :selected =>      @sub_category.analyst || 0) %>
```

and my model looks likes this:

```
@@analyst_names = ["", "foo", "bar"]

belongs_to :category
has_many :products

 def analyst_name
    @@analyst_names[analyst.to_i || 0]
  end

 def self.analyst_names
    @@analyst_names
  end
```

The error when trying to load the page is: undefined local variable or method `analyst_names'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For me it looks like you should move some stuff to the model instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your model is called, so I'll call it `MyModel` for now.

In your view, you're going to want to replace `analyst_names` with `MyModel.analyst_names`, because otherwise it thinks `analyst_names` is a local variable in the view, and then it can't find that variable.

You might benefit from reading about scope (some links about it are [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) and [here](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/ruby_tutorial/scope.html)).